# For an $m\times n$ matrix why does $m \le n$ for the matrix to have linear independent rows?

Tags: linear-algebra

Simple linear algebra question but not sure how to find the answer.

For an $m\times n$ matrix why does $m \le n$ for the matrix to have linear independent rows?

For example here is a 3x2 matrix A, as in Ax = b:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3\\
2&1\\
-3&7\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
5\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It seems to me that $m > n$ and all the lines are independent?

Comment: In an m x n matrix we can think of the m rows as m vectors in an n dimensional space.  If m> n there are more vectors than the dimension of the space.

Comment: The example that you've added to the question is not a matrix but an equation involving two matrices and a vector. I could solve to show you that the bottom row of the first matrix can be expressed in terms of the two other rows, but I'm not sure that would convince you.

Comment: The rows of A are not independent. (17/5) times the first row - (16/5) times the second row is equal to the third row.

Answer (score 2):

For a $m×n$ matrix the row space of matrix is given by span of $m$ rows which can be corresponded with the subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ as the row vectors are of the form of $n$ tuple. As we know, if the number of spanning vectors of a vector space are greater than its dimension then those vectors cannot be linearly independent. Hence number of vectors must be either equal to dimension or less (in case of less vector it will not span the whole vector space but only a subspace of it). Therefore, for row vectors to span a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ (dimension of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is $n$ ) the number of row vectors can be either $n$ or less than $n$ then only they can be linearly independent. Since number of row vectors are $m$, hence $m \le n$ for the matrix to have linearly independent rows.

Answer (score 1):

The length of a linearly independent list is less than or equal to the length of a basis of a vector space. The row vectors are $1\times n$ row vectors in the vector space $R^{1,n}$, the dimension of this vector space is $n$. Thus the length of the basis of this vector space is $n$. Thus, if your $m\times n$ matrix is such that $m>n$, then there are more than $n$ row vectors, and they can't be linearly independent because the length of a linearly independent list of vectors must be less than or equal to the length of the basis of the vector space. In general the theorem is that the length of a a linearly independent list is less than or equal the length of a spanning list.

Comment: Thanks I udpated OP. maybe you can see what I am getting at?

Answer (score 1):

Take a simple case. For a $3\times2$ matrix,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
a&b\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
the third row is just a multiple of the first and second, $r_3=ar_1+br_2$. For a $2\times3$ matrix,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&a\\
0&1&b\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
there is not any way you can make $r_2$ from $r_1$ or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, I updated OP, not sure how to get the matrix into one line but hopefully you get the idea. It seems like the three rows are linearly independent to me?